# Using JWT in a app after the user logged in correctly

Tags: android, ios, jwt

I'm currently developing an app for the company I work for that has a username / password login system. But i'm still deciding what is the best aproach for this app after the user is logged in to keep him logged in.

[JWT's](https://jwt.io/introduction/) are looking promising but the app has users that sometimes don't visit the app for longer periods of time (2 weeks+). JWT's are suppose to have expiry dates (And lets keep it that way). But what would be a good way to keep a user loggedin even after his JWT is expired in the app?

From a security standpoint (And me as developer) I would say just log them out. And let them login again. But my manager has other thoughts about that. Is there another way to achieve this other than completly removing the expiry date of the JWT's (I'm never going to remove the expiry date. If the expiry is removed it would be just as safe as not having a login system at all....)

Hope to hear your thoughts about it.
Kind regards,
Kevin Walter

Comment: If your devices have biometric capabilities (TouchID/FaceID) give them the option of saving their username and password in the keychain and use biometrics to retrieve the credentials from the keychain. If they don't have biometric then you can allow a fallback to passcode or only save the user id and make them re-nter their password. If your company has Azure AD and you only need authentication, not claims, then OAuth is a good option too. OAuth can automatically refresh an expired token without needing the username/password ( the user needs to log in again when the refresh limit is reached)

Comment: The keychain option is a great idea. I will look into that! We don't have Azure AD

Comment: There are many other authentication sources that can support OAuth as well, I just mentioned Azure AD as it is common these days in enterprise

Answer (score 1):

We typically use OAuth2 and have the access token be a JWT.  That way we can short circuit the round trip as long as the JWT is valid, and then use a refresh flow with the refresh token to get a new JWT access token, so long as the refresh token is valid.

Access tokens can live a short time (4-8 hours) and the refresh token can be long-lived (30-365 days).  So long as the app keeps the refresh token secure (in the keychain for example), you can provide reasonable security without a bad user experience.